# pandas .diff() but use first cell as difference between last cell in prior column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

say that i have a df in the following format:

```
year        2016  2017  2018  2019  2020  min  max    avg
month                                                    
2021-01-01   284   288   311   383   476  284  476  357.4
2021-02-01   301   315   330   388   441  301  441  359.6
2021-03-01   303   331   341   400   475  303  475  375.4
2021-04-01   283   300   339   419   492  283  492  372.6
2021-05-01   287   288   346   420   445  287  445  359.7
2021-06-01   283   292   340   424   446  283  446  359.1
2021-07-01   294   296   360   444   452  294  452  370.3
2021-08-01   294   315   381   445   451  294  451  375.9
2021-09-01   288   331   405   464   459  288  464  385.6
2021-10-01   327   349   424   457   453  327  457  399.1
2021-11-01   316   351   413   469   471  316  471  401.0
2021-12-01   259   329   384   467   465  259  467  375.7
```

and i would like to get the difference of the 2020 column by using `df['delta'] = df['2020'].diff()`

this will obviously return NaN for the first value in the column. how can i make it so that it automatically interprets that diff as the difference between the FIRST value of 2020 and the LAST value of 2019?

Comment: Your `month` index is really 'Jan','Feb','Mar',... (or even 1,2,3...), not a specific year `2021-01-01`. Why not make the month index less confusing?

Comment: @scmi this was due to a code error rolling over graphs but I was eager to get the question out. the month index is normally Jan Feb Mar etc.

Comment: visualnotsobasic: ok sure, but for everyone else looking at this one, don't name your index something cryptic and self-contradictory.

Comment: i wouldn't exactly call that cryptic or self contradictory... it's also not relevant to the question. i don't have a problem with constructive criticism but you're effectively just looking for something wrong here.

Comment: visualnotsobasic: no I'm not, and it is constructive. Here, index `month=='2021-02-01'` really only means `Feb` across the years 2016..2020. There is a real constructive point, and that is *"How should we best represent month-only (as a date? integer 1..12? enum? string? categorical?) such that we get correct sort-order in aggregation/stacking/pivoting(/plotting, because matplotlib might not understand)"* This is something I've struggled with too. pandas can be clunky. Categoricals are *still* not a first-class type, and don't really survive export/import. (by contrast R does things better)

Comment: so i'm graphing it as a date, i'll paste the code. i'm struggling with converting the index to just display the date. unless you think we can take this to chat, it might be easier than bogging down the question but i don't have the rep to be able to do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230615/discussion-between-visualnotsobasic-and-smci).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want only for 2020:

```
df["delta"] = pd.concat([df["2019"], df["2020"]]).diff().tail(len(df))
```

Prints:

```
          year  2016  2017  2018  2019  2020  min  max    avg  delta
0   2021-01-01   284   288   311   383   476  284  476  357.4    9.0
1   2021-02-01   301   315   330   388   441  301  441  359.6  -35.0
2   2021-03-01   303   331   341   400   475  303  475  375.4   34.0
3   2021-04-01   283   300   339   419   492  283  492  372.6   17.0
4   2021-05-01   287   288   346   420   445  287  445  359.7  -47.0
5   2021-06-01   283   292   340   424   446  283  446  359.1    1.0
6   2021-07-01   294   296   360   444   452  294  452  370.3    6.0
7   2021-08-01   294   315   381   445   451  294  451  375.9   -1.0
8   2021-09-01   288   331   405   464   459  288  464  385.6    8.0
9   2021-10-01   327   349   424   457   453  327  457  399.1   -6.0
10  2021-11-01   316   351   413   469   471  316  471  401.0   18.0
11  2021-12-01   259   329   384   467   465  259  467  375.7   -6.0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try `unstack` then do the `diff`, notice the first item in 2016 will still be `NaN`

```
out = df.drop(['min','max','avg'],1).unstack().diff().unstack(0)
            2016  2017  2018  2019  2020
2021-01-01   NaN  29.0 -18.0  -1.0   9.0
2021-02-01  17.0  27.0  19.0   5.0 -35.0
2021-03-01   2.0  16.0  11.0  12.0  34.0
2021-04-01 -20.0 -31.0  -2.0  19.0  17.0
2021-05-01   4.0 -12.0   7.0   1.0 -47.0
2021-06-01  -4.0   4.0  -6.0   4.0   1.0
2021-07-01  11.0   4.0  20.0  20.0   6.0
2021-08-01   0.0  19.0  21.0   1.0  -1.0
2021-09-01  -6.0  16.0  24.0  19.0   8.0
2021-10-01  39.0  18.0  19.0  -7.0  -6.0
2021-11-01 -11.0   2.0 -11.0  12.0  18.0
2021-12-01 -57.0 -22.0 -29.0  -2.0  -6.0
```